# What "really" happens to an evolving state which goes through degeneracy? (and relation to Berry phase)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, perturbation-theory, time-evolution, berry-pancharatnam-phase

Say I have a time dependent Hamiltonian $H(t)$ and I let an initial eigenstate $|\psi_n\rangle$ evolve according to the Schrodinger equation, so that at time $t$ the state is $|\psi_n(t)\rangle$ with energy $E_n(t)$.

Whenever I encounter such problems, they are usually (except for very specific cases) treated with perturbation theory, under the assumption that the state does not change "too much", and that the energy levels are always non-degenerate. I recently realized that I do not really know what happens to the state assuming that there is degeneracy at some time $t_0$. If at $t_0$ there are two orthogonal eigenstates $|\psi_n(t_0)\rangle,|\psi_n'(t_0)\rangle$ with energy $E_n(t_0)$, how do I keep "evolving" the state after time $t_0$? Which state is the "correct" one to evolve? (there is actually an entire eigenspace to choose from).

I know that there are criterions (say, due to Kato) under which there is a unique way to choose an eigenstate when going through degeneracy so that the evolution of the spectral curves remains analytic along the degenerate time point. Intuitively, this seems like the "correct" choice. But other than the intuition I do not see why physically this should be the case. Or more concretely, is there some way to prove this using the Schrodinger equation?

My motivation is actually confusion related to the Berry phase. Assume that my (adiabatically) evolving state goes through a degeneracy (and this happens in a lot of famous examples, for instance the computation of the Berry phase for a spin in a magnetic field). For instance, I follow the 4th eigenstate, and at some point it shares the same energy as the 5th eigenstate. So the 5th spectral curve meets the 4th one at some time $t_0$, they intersect, and switch positions. When computing the Berry phase - which eigenstate should I start "following" from that point? In most examples I see, I should now start following that state which used to be the 5th (because its corresponding energy level is now actually the 4th). But is this the 'right' thing to do? As I said above, the intuitive choice is actually to keep following the same spectral curve I followed from before. But this choice also has problems; First of all, it is 'artificial' in the sense that it evolves some "choice" of the observer, and knowledge of the behavior of the spectral curves at a neighborhood of the time point (and not just at the time point itself). Also, this choice does not guarantee that as the state completes a cycle in the parameter space, the state will return to be as it was at the initial time (up to a phase).

Sorry if this is a bit philosophical. I'm new to this theory and I am wondering what would be the right way to treat such a problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If there is a degeneracy, the evolution can not be adiabatic. The computation of Berry phase for spin-1/2 in a magnetic field never touches the point where the magnetic field vanishes.